# Refactoring some code i found this. I assume it should be inside a constructor. Any thoughts about this being outside the class?

Tags: reactjs, constructor

I'm refactoring some code from an application im developing alongside other colleagues. I have thoughts wether this should be outside the class or inside it in a constructor.

Thank you all!

-Charlie[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `BRANCHES` array is a constant field and it is perfectly ok for it to be defined outside the `BranchSelector` class

Declaring this way gives you the flexibility to export the `BRANCHES` array and import it in some other file too

You don't get any advantage by defining it within the constructor.

However if cases arise where you need to modify and update this array by adding or removing items, then it makes perfect sense for it to be specific to the class component and be defined as a state